# LTspice - using an encrypted file

Tags: ltspice, buck, texas-instruments

Is there a way to use a TI encrypted file in LTspice, specifically the TI PN TPSM63610?

Answer (score 4):

Nope. Encrypted SPICE models/subcircuits/libraries can only be used in the software they were encrypted for. So the “TPM63610 PSPICE Transient Model” can only be used in PSpice. Luckily TI provides a free download of [PSPICE-FOR-TI](https://www.ti.com/tool/PSPICE-FOR-TI).

I should also mention that the .zip file for the model download [looks to be corrupted](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/1289066/tpsm63610-pspice-model-on-product-page-seems-corrupted) and is also missing the actual library file. Here is a link to a corrected version:

https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/196/TPSM63610_5F00_TRANS.zip

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!!